# Is there any benefit of uploading package on nuget?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, nugetgallery

I am wondering there is no benefit of uploading package on nuget then why people spent too much time to create a package and upload it on nuget?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can distributes packages without using nuget.

But think:

- How will you manage versions?
- How will you Define dependencies for the packages?
- Where you will explain technical specifications and documentation of package?
- How will you know if your package is useful or not?
- How will you know that how many times users has downloaded your package?
- How will ensure to your user that your package is valid and went through security checksum?

If you have all the answers then there is no need of uploading packages on nuget.

Thanks